# Lasers can demagnetize ferromagnets?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, laser

How is it possible to demagnetize a magnet with a laser?

Source: http://www.helmholtz-berlin.de/pubbin/news_seite?nid=13657&sprache=en&typoid

And the paper: http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v88/i21/e214404

How does this work?

Comment: The abstract you linked to explains it.  The laser excites electrons which, according to the abstract, are able to alter the spin of electrons in the ferromagnetic material and destroy the magnetic domains.  They call it "spin currents".

Comment: But this is not a "common" method, not very popular like the others... Maybe because its not "complete"?

Comment: "Common" and "popular" have nothing to do with it.  Demagnetizing a magnet is trivial.  Just heat it up above its [Curie temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature).  The demagnetization by laser is interesting because it seems like it works without heating the material to above the Curie temp.

Comment: @BrandonEnright Do you think this is an effective method? Most of these experiments we're applied on small samples, would this still apply to any ferromagnet regardless? What do you think?

Comment: With a short but intense enough laser burst it should scale up just fine.  I wouldn't call it efficient though if you're going to compare it to heating.  Why build a big frick'n laser to demagnetize when pretty much any heat source will do.

Comment: @BrandonEnright because this method is super fast. And probably saves more energy. I think it's efficient enough to fully demagnetize the sample?

Comment: Pretty much nothing is more efficient than getting something hot.  I have no idea what the efficiency of the laser system is but you can pretty well be sure it's way less efficient then just heating the sample.

Comment: @BrandonEnright I agree, but don't you find heating a massive waste of energy? I mean, a 5 kg ferromagnet might need kJ or even MJ of energy to demagnetize it. This system probably does it faster, and less energy is used in the process. I will contact the researchers figure this out.

Comment: I think asking which is likely to be more efficient would make a good top-level question.  You should ask it here.

Comment: @BrandonEnright I might post a newer question later. After studying more about the matter. Thank you!

Comment: @BrandonEnright Do you think a short burst high intensity laser needs to be continuously functional? e/g continuously powered?

Comment: I don't know much about laser engineering but my guess is that they store a huge amount of energy in a bank of capacitors so that they can deliver a powerful burst very quickly.

Comment: @BrandonEnright Yes, thats how must of them work. They call them "Pulse" lasers. And most of these demagnetization methods use those pulse lasers.

Comment: @BrandonEnright from this method do you think the laser's must focus on the material completely? Or focus at one point and can cause a total demagnetization? That I could not figure out...

Comment: I'm sure if the laser has enough power it can be defocused and demagnetize a larger region.  The effect is all about imparting enough energy to the electrons that they're able to move through the material like an electron gas and change spin of other electrons.  There is no reason why you couldn't use a highly defocused "wall of light" laser to demagnetize the entire surface at once provided it had enough power.

Comment: @BrandonEnright phenomenal! Focus a small/powerful laser beam on the material with enough power cause total demagnetization! I rate of power is dependent on the hysteresis of the material(i/e it's magnetic properties), if it's a material with low coercivity like soft iron I doubt it would required a lot of power. I assume it's easily demagnetized from a laser source maybe?

Comment: @BrandonEnright, what do you think of my last post?

Comment: @M.A.A. Are you aware that we're talking about demagnetizing the **surface** of a magnet? About so deep as a laser can penetrate the material...